# Interpretation of 'incorrect' results of chi square test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, assumptions

I use the chisq.test() function for the goodness of fit test. I run the test through a range of variables, and in some cases get the following message:

```r
In chisq.test(TBL_all_f) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect.
```

The values of my variable are split into 20 bins, and I believe that mathematically this output means that the numbers of observations in some bins are low. At the same time, this is not true for all my variables, and for the sake of consistency I'd like to keep all bins. My question is how I should interpret the 'may be incorrect' message? May I assume that it means the X-squared might be overstated, and the p-value understated, so that I can take the p-value as a conservative estimate?

Comment: Its not the values of the observations but the expected values that are the main issue. The p-values are normally computed using the chi-squared approximation and may not be particularly accurate depending on several things (including the extent to which the expected values vary). You mentioned "bins"; are you discretizing a continuous variable to generate these bins?

Comment: Don't trust the conventional wisdom on this, because it tends to be too limiting.  In particular, when the number of bins is "large," having small expectations (less than $5$) in a bunch of the bins is usually not a problem.  One of the best and simplest ways to get your question answered is to conduct a quick permutation or Monte-Carlo computation of the p value: if it's sufficiently close to the chi-squared p-value, you should be OK.  I doubt the chi-squared p-value can always be considered a conservative estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following table of counts; rows are separate samples and
columns are various 'bins'.

```r
TAB = rbind(c(10, 21, 31,  3), c(22, 40, 70,  2))
TAB
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10   21   31    3
[2,]   22   40   70    2
```

The 4th column has very low counts. As you suspect, this gives
rise to a warning message in R.

```r
chsq.out = chisq.test(TAB); chsq.out
Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 1.9923, df = 3, p-value = 0.574
```

Specifically, the warning message appears when any of the expected
counts (obtained from row and column tables according to the hull
hypothesis that bins have similar proportions for both row populations) is 5 or smaller.

```r
chsq.out$exp
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 10.45226 19.92462 32.98995 1.633166
[2,] 21.54774 41.07538 68.01005 3.366834
```

The expected counts for the 4th bin are both smaller than 5.

One could combine bins for the 3rd and 4th columns, to give a new
table that would not have such small expected counts. But you say
you want to keep all the bins in your analysis.

In R, one can simulate reasonably accurate P-value upon request.

```r
chisq.test(TAB, sim=TRUE)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TAB
X-squared = 1.9923, df = NA, p-value = 0.5942
```

The resulting P-value $0.594 > 0.05 = 5\%$ so that the null hypothesis
is not rejected at the 5% level of significance. The simulated P-value
$0.594$ is not much different from the original questionable one $0.574.$

In this example, we would have reached the correct conclusion (not to reject $H_0$) with the questionable P-value, but without being really
sure that decision is appropriate.

One major concern about expected values $E_{ij}$ that are too small is as follows: The chi-squared statistic
$H = \sum_{ij} \frac{(X_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}},$ consisting of eight terms, has $E_{ij}$'s in the the denominators. $[X_{ij}$ are the observed counts in `TAB`.]

Thus, an expected
value that is by chance too small may inflate $H,$ give too small a P-value, and lead to unwarranted rejection of the null hypothesis.
However, tiny $E_{ij}$'s may lead to other kinds of inaccuracies, so
I would not want to say that the questionable chi-squared statistics
are *always* too large.

Especially if the null hypothesis is rejected, you may want to know which cells of the table make the most notable
contributions to the chi-squared statistic. Then you can look at Pearson
residuals. Their squares sum to the chi-squared statistic, and their
signs reflect whether $X_{ij}-E_{ij}$ is positive or negative.
Usually, Pearson residuals with absolute values larger than 1.5 or 2.0
are of particular interest. [Of course, if the expected counts are
questionable, then the Pearson residuals may also be questionable.]

In the example above, the eight Pearson residuals are as shown below,
none of them remarkable.

```r
chsq.out$resi
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
[1,] -0.13988924  0.2409160 -0.3464585  1.069549
[2,]  0.09742908 -0.1677915  0.2412990 -0.744912
```

*Note:* Here is another fictitious table of counts that
has a questionable P-value on account of small expected counts.
In this case the null hypothesis is rejected.

```r
TAB2 = rbind(c(0, 21, 20,  3), c(18, 40, 80,  2));  TAB2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0   21   20    3
[2,]   18   40   80    2

chsq2 = chisq.test(TAB2);  chsq2
Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB2) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB2
X-squared = 13.783, df = 3, p-value = 0.003216

chsq2$exp  # THREE expected counts < 5
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,]  4.304348 14.58696 23.91304 1.195652
[2,] 13.695652 46.41304 76.08696 3.804348

chsq2$resi   # NOTE residual (1,1)
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -2.074692  1.6791204 -0.8001976  1.6501288
[2,]  1.163097 -0.9413349  0.4486003 -0.9250818

chisq.test(TAB2, sim=TRUE)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

 data:  TAB2
 X-squared = 13.783, df = NA, p-value = 0.005497
```

Comment: The problem with these examples is that they all use small numbers of bins, whereas the question concerns a substantially larger number.  When you redo such simulations with many bins, the answer is no longer so clear.